# How to save spark streaming data in cassandra

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

**build.sbt**
Below are the contents included in build.sbt file

---

```
val sparkVersion = "1.6.3" 
scalaVersion := "2.10.5" 
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven" 
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion,
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % sparkVersion)
libraryDependencies +="datastax" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.3-s_2.10"
libraryDependencies +="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.1.0"
```

---

**Command to initialize shell:**
The below command is the shell initialization procedure I followed

***`/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/spark/bin/spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.3-s_2.10 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 –jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.3.jar`***

**Note:**
Here I specified jar specifically because SBT couldn’t fetch the required libraries of spark streaming kafka used at creation of kafkaStream in later sections

**Import required libraries:**

This section includes libraries to be imported that are used in various cases of the REPL session

***`import org.apache.spark.SparkConf; import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext; import org.apache.spark.streaming.Seconds; import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils; import com.datastax.spark.connector._ ; import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._ ;`***

**Setting up Spark Streaming Configuration:**

Here am configuring configurations required for spark streaming context

---

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("KafkaReceiver")
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true"); // Required to set this to true because during // shell initialization or starting we a spark context is created with configurations of highlighted
conf.setMaster("local"); // then we are assigning those cofigurations locally
```

---

**Creation of SparkStreamingContext using above configurations:**
Using configurations defined above we create a spark streaming context in the below way

***`val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1)); // Seconds here describe the interval to fetch`***

**Creating a Kafka stream using above Spark Streaming Context aka SSC:**
Here ssc is spark streaming context that was created above,
“localhost:2181”  is ZKquoram
"spark-streaming-consumer-group" is consumer group
Map("test3" -> 5) is Map(“topic” -> number of  partitions )

***`val kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181","spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("test3" -> 5)).map(_._2)`***

**Note** 
Values fetched when the **kafkaStream** object is printed, using ***`kafkaStream.print()`*** are shown in below image 
[image]

---

```
85052,19,960.00,0,2017-08-29 14:52:41,17,VISHAL_GWY01_HT1,26,VISHAL_GTWY17_PRES_01,1,2,4                                                             
85053,19,167.00,0,2017-08-29 14:52:41,17,VISHAL_GWY01_HT1,25,VISHAL_GTWY1_Temp_01,1,2,4                                                              
85054,19,960.00,0,2017-08-29 14:52:41,17,VISHAL_GWY01_HT1,26,VISHAL_GTWY17_PRES_01,1,2,4                                                             
85055,19,167.00,0,2017-08-29 14:52:54,17,VISHAL_GWY01_HT1,25,VISHAL_GTWY1_Temp_01,1,2,4                                                              
85056,19,960.00,0,2017-08-29 14:52:54,17,VISHAL_GWY01_HT1,26,VISHAL_GTWY17_PRES_01,1,2,4                                                             
85057,19,167.00,0,2017-08-29 14:52:55,17,VISHAL_GWY01_HT1,25,VISHAL_GTWY1_Temp_01,1,2,4                                                              
85058,19,960.00,0,2017-08-29 14:52:55,17,VISHAL_GWY01_HT1,26,VISHAL_GTWY17_PRES_01,1,2,4                                                             

17/09/02 18:25:25 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1504376716000 ms.0 from job set of time 1504376716000 ms                             
17/09/02 18:25:25 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 9.661 s for time 1504376716000 ms (execution: 0.021 s)                                             
17/09/02 18:25:25 INFO JobScheduler: Starting job streaming job 1504376717000 ms.0 from job set of time 1504376717000 ms
```

---

**Transforming the kafkaStream and saving in Cassandra:**

---

```
kafkaStream.foreachRDD( rdd => { 
if (! rdd.isEmpty()) { 
rdd.map( line => { 
val arr = line.split(",");
(arr(0), arr(1), arr(2), arr(3), arr(4), arr(5), arr(6), arr(7), arr(8), arr(9), arr(10), arr(11))
}). saveToCassandra("test", "sensorfeedVals", SomeColumns(
"tableid", "ccid", "paramval", "batVal", "time", "gwid", "gwhName", "snid", "snhName", "snStatus", "sd", "MId")
)
} else {
 println("No records to save")
}
}
)
```

---

**Start ssc:**

Using ***`ssc.start`*** you can start the streaming

Issues am facing here are:
 1. Printing of the content of stream is happening only after I enter **exit** or **Ctrl+C**
 2. Whenever I use **ssc.start** does it start streaming immediately In REPL? Without giving time to enter **ssc.awaitTermination** 
 3. Main issue when I tried to save normally in below procedure                ***

```
val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("key3", 3), ("key4", 4)))
collection.saveToCassandra("test", "kv", SomeColumns("key", "value"))
```

---

am able to save in Cassandra but whenever am trying to save in Cassandra using the logic shown in **Transforming the kafkaStream and saving in Cassandra:** I couldn't extract each value from string and save it in respective columns of Cassandra tables!

Comment: What do you mean "You couldn't save those values", is there an exception? Do no values show up? Are you sure there are values to save?

Comment: @RussS edited the question with values shown up when I printed using kafkaStream.print().

Comment: @RussS "I couldn't save those values" means which ever values am fetching using kafkaStream, I couldn't iterate over those and extract each individual value of  record in the csv and then save them into Cassandra.

Comment: What does "You couldn't iterate over them" mean. I still don't understand. Like the records aren't being written and when you read from Cassandra the records don't show up? Or an exception is thrown which stops you from iterating?

Comment: @RussS when am trying to iterate over that rdd using the logic specified in "Transforming the kafkaStream and saving in Cassandra" part of the above post an exception is thrown ! 
Stating 
"Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-5" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraC
onnector"

Comment: Why not use dstream.saveToCassandra API ? You could do the transformation in the dstream.map

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector`

Means the classpath has not been correctly setup for your application. Make sure you are using the `--packages` option when launching your application as is noted in the [SCC Docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md#prerequisites)

For your other issues

You don't need `awaitTermination` in the REPL because the repl will not instantly quit after starting the streaming context. That call is there for an application which may have no further instructions to prevent the main thread from exiting.

Start will start the streaming immediately.

Comment: But I wonder why am I able to save some set of values as given below 

val collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(("key3", 3), ("key4", 4)))
collection.saveToCassandra("test", "kv", SomeColumns("key", "value"))


with in same shell I opened to process my logic

Comment: That would depend on how you have started your shell and where the tasks for that operation were run. The error though explicitly tells you the classpath is not setup correctly on a machine. If you had the full trace it would tell you which machine.

Comment: am using --packages option, please check the "Command to initialize shell" section of the question ! 
And classpath has been setup correctly ! As soon as I got that excpetion I tried to check and resolve based on that exception!

Comment: Why do you have a build sbt if this is running in the Repl? Also why aren't you using the latest 1.6.X release of the SCC? I don't know enough about HortonWorks to understand how they may be changing about the classloader. I would at the minimum use the very latest SCC release. https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector#169

Comment: If you check https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md#prerequisites part of your SSC Docs link that you posted in reply you can understand why i used build.sbit  when am running on REPL! 

I followed same source to know the procedure how to save in Cassandra! But when I failed in modifying the code as per requirement i was given ! That's where am seeking help !

Comment: That's only for if you are using `sbt` as is specified in the documentation. You just need to use the `spark-shell` instructions. Anyway still try version 1.6.9 which is the latest 1.6 release.

Comment: I modified SBT as per the requirements of the program ! Okay will try to modify version to 1.6.9 and check if it goes fine ! But I think it is not major reason behind ! Because I tried to save as mentioned in above comments in the same shell instance which I ran my logic piece of code !  That part of code able to save the values but my logic is not able to being within same shell !

Comment: You need to modify the packages command, build.sbt is for If you are building your own Standalone application outside of the spark shell. There's no reason to use a build SBT file if you are using the sparkshell.

Comment: Sorry, am completely beginner into the world of Big Data mainly spark and scala! and changing version to 1.6.9 also raised same exception!       "Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraC
onnector"

Comment: There are only 2 things I could guess then. It could be a scala 2.10 reflection thread safety issue which comes up sometimes. Or hortonworks distro is doing something slightly strange to the classpath. You can try placing all of the SCC dependencies on the root classloader which may help but this would require building an assembly fat jar and placing in your spark lib dir.

Comment: Can you please share the references to do the tasks you mentioned ! They sound complete strange to me!

Comment: Hi @RussS Please check answers below ! I found the solution and resolved the issue in the described answer. Thanks for coming forward to help.

Answer (score 1):

A line or two lines of code which related to contexts is causing the issue here!

I found the solution when i walked through the topics of context!

Here I was running multiple contexts but they are independent to each other.

I have initialized shell with below command:

***`/usr/hdp/2.6.0.3-8/spark/bin/spark-shell --packages datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:1.6.3-s_2.10 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 –jars spark-streaming-kafka-assembly_2.10-1.6.3.jar`***

So when shell starts A spark context with properties of Datastax connector are initialized.

Later I created some configurations and using those configurations created a spark streaming context. Using this context I have created kafkaStream. This kafkaStream is having only properties of SSC but not SC, so here raised the issue of storing in to cassandra.

I have tried to resolve it in the below and succeeded!

---

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark-Kafka-Streaming").setMaster("local[*]").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1"))
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(10))
```

---

***Thanks everyone who came forward to support! 
Let me know if any more best possible ways to achieve it!***

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach is to convert a stream as a dataframe for foreachRDD API, convert the RDD to DataFrame and save to cassandra using SparkSQL-Cassandra Datasource API. Below is a simple code snippet where I am saving the Twitter tweets to a Cassandra Table

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  if (rdd.count() > 0) {
    val data = rdd.filter(status => status.getLang.equals("en")).map(status => TweetsClass(status.getId,
      status.getCreatedAt.toGMTString(),
      status.getUser.getLocation,
      status.getText)).toDF()
    //Save the data to Cassandra
    data.write.
      format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").
      options(Map(
        "table" -> "sentiment_tweets",
        "keyspace" -> "My Keyspace",
        "cluster" -> "My Cluster")).mode(SaveMode.Append).save()

  }
})
```

Comment: Please help me by making a simple Sample code for the data format that am getting through stream ! Please check the data format in "Creating a Kafka stream using above Spark Streaming Context aka SSC" Section of the question!

Comment: Hi Ishan Kumar,  Please check answers below ! I found the solution and resolved the issue in the described answer. Thanks for coming forward to help.