# Parse JSON Data and save to MongoDB in PySpark

Tags: json, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I Am using PySpark and fetching data from Kafka Broker.

The below code helps me to do that :

```
import json
import sys
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils, TopicAndPartition
from pymongo import MongoClient

# Spark Context created here
sc = SparkContext("local[*]", appName="TwitterStreamKafka")

#Spark Streaming Context Created Here
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

#Kafka Stream Created Here
tweets = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer", {"twitter": 1})

tweets.pprint()

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Extracted the JSON from tweets using below code :

```
tweet_json = tweets.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1]))
```

Now I want to insert this ***tweet_json*** to MongoDB. But couldn't get how to do that.

Checked Spark-MongoConnector it says it requires DataFrame to store in MongoDB

But Type of ***tweet_json*** is ***"pyspark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream"***

How can I convert this into Dataframe to store into MongoDB?

or

How to save the fetched tweet to MongoDB in using PySpark

Thank you in advance!

After edits suggested in program, i edited it in below way:

---

```
import json
import sys
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils, TopicAndPartition
from pymongo import MongoClient
def convert(rdd):
    df_json = rdd.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1])).toDF()
    return df_json
# Spark Context created here
sc = SparkContext("local[*]", appName="TwitterStreamKafka")
#Spark Streaming Context Created Here
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
#Kafka Stream Created Here
tweets = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer", {"twitter": 1})
#Tweets Printed Here
tweets.pprint()
tweets.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: convert(rdd).write\
                  .format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource').mode('append')
                  .option('database',Twitter).option('collection',RestTwitter).save())
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

---

Then initialized spark submit in below way:

***`spark-submit --conf "spark.mongodb.inuri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/TwitterDB.RestDatareadPreference=primaryPreferred" --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/TwitterDB.RestData"  --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.0.0 --jars spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.0.0.jar PySparkTwitter.py`***

It raised the following error:

***File "/home/hduser/test/PySparkTwitter.py", line 24, in convert
    df_json = rdd.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1])).toDF()
AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'toDF'***

Data Format of CreateStream:

```
(None, '{"lang": "en", "id": 967004613332303873, "favorited": false, "possibly_sensitive": false, "is_quote_status": false, "geo": null, "user": {"lang": "en", "profile_use_background_image": false, "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/19908749/1517325981", "is_translator": false, "id": 19908749, "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF", "favourites_count": 1912, "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/921307498409230336/VWkCvBcu_normal.jpg", "friends_count": 1960, "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/222053103/twitter-image-bg.jpg", "has_extended_profile": false, "profile_link_color": "AB0D0D", "screen_name": "ZNConsulting", "geo_enabled": true, "url": "", "profile_text_color": "000000", "default_profile": false, "utc_offset": 3600, "is_translation_enabled": false, "statuses_count": 5833, "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/222053103/twitter-image-bg.jpg", "verified": false, "name": "ZN Consulting", "notifications": false, "protected": false, "id_str": "19908749", "translator_type": "none", "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/921307498409230336/VWkCvBcu_normal.jpg", "created_at": "Mon Feb 02 14:28:00 +0000 2009", "time_zone": "Brussels", "listed_count": 253, "follow_request_sent": false, "location": "Brussels; Our website:", "profile_background_color": "F7F7F7", "contributors_enabled": false, "entities": {"url": {"urls": [{"display_url": "znconsulting.com", "expanded_url": "http://znconsulting.com", "url": "", "indices": [0, 23]}]}, "description": {"urls": []}}, "default_profile_image": false, "following": false, "followers_count": 2312, "description": "The #digital communication agency in #Brussels. Strategy, digital campaigns, analysis & #socialmedia. #Hyperthinking to give you the #DigitalAdvantage \\ud83d\\ude0e", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "C7C7C7"}, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "contributors": null, "retweet_count": 0, "text": "Following user feedback, #Google is now blocking intrusive ads with a built-in adblocker in #Chrome \\u26d4\\n\\n", "retweeted": false, "truncated": false, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "id_str": "967004613332303873", "source": "<a href=\\"https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\">TweetDeck</a>", "created_at": "Fri Feb 23 11:54:00 +0000 2018", "metadata": {"iso_language_code": "en", "result_type": "recent"}, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "entities": {"symbols": [], "urls": [{"display_url": "theguardian.com/technology/201\\u2026", "expanded_url": "https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2018/feb/15/google-adblocker-chrome-browser", "url": "", "indices": [103, 126]}], "user_mentions": [], "hashtags": [{"text": "Google", "indices": [25, 32]}, {"text": "Chrome", "indices": [92, 99]}]}, "coordinates": null, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "place": null, "favorite_count": 0}')
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to convert the dstream of rdds to a dstream of dataframes. Use **.foreachRDD** for such cases.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sql = SQLContext(sc)

def _construct_key(previous_key, separator, new_key):
    if previous_key:
        return "{}{}{}".format(previous_key, separator, new_key)
    else:
        return new_key

def _flatten_JSON(nested_dict, separator='_', root_keys_to_ignore=set()):
    assert isinstance(nested_dict, dict)
    assert isinstance(separator, str)
    flattened_dict = dict()

    def _flatten(object_, key):        
        if isinstance(object_, dict):
            for object_key in object_:
                if not (not key and object_key in root_keys_to_ignore):
                    _flatten(object_[object_key], _construct_key(key, separator, object_key))
        elif isinstance(object_, list) or isinstance(object_, set):
            for index, item in enumerate(object_):
                _flatten(item, _construct_key(key, separator, index))
        else:
            flattened_dict[key] = object_

    _flatten(nested_dict, None)
    return flattened_dict

def convert(rdd):
    df_json = rdd.map(lambda x: _flatten_JSON(json.loads(x[1]))).toDF()
    return df_json

def write_mongo(rdd):
    try:
        convert(rdd).write\
          .format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource').mode('append')\
          .option('database',NAME).option('collection',COLLECTION_MONGODB).save()
    except:
        pass

tweets.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: write_mongo(rdd))
```

Also, you need to give conf and packages alongwith spark-submit according to your version,

```
/bin/spark-submit --conf "spark.mongodb.inuri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/DATABASE.COLLECTION_NAME?readPreference=primaryPreferred"
                  --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/DATABASE.COLLECTION_NAME" 
                  --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0
                  tester.py
```

Here is format of createStream fetched data

```
(None, '{"lang": "en", "id": 967004613332303873, "favorited": false, "possibly_sensitive": false, "is_quote_status": false, "geo": null, "user": {"lang": "en", "profile_use_background_image": false, "profile_banner_url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/19908749/1517325981", "is_translator": false, "id": 19908749, "profile_sidebar_border_color": "FFFFFF", "favourites_count": 1912, "profile_background_tile": false, "profile_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/921307498409230336/VWkCvBcu_normal.jpg", "friends_count": 1960, "profile_background_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/222053103/twitter-image-bg.jpg", "has_extended_profile": false, "profile_link_color": "AB0D0D", "screen_name": "ZNConsulting", "geo_enabled": true, "url": "", "profile_text_color": "000000", "default_profile": false, "utc_offset": 3600, "is_translation_enabled": false, "statuses_count": 5833, "profile_background_image_url_https": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_background_images/222053103/twitter-image-bg.jpg", "verified": false, "name": "ZN Consulting", "notifications": false, "protected": false, "id_str": "19908749", "translator_type": "none", "profile_image_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/921307498409230336/VWkCvBcu_normal.jpg", "created_at": "Mon Feb 02 14:28:00 +0000 2009", "time_zone": "Brussels", "listed_count": 253, "follow_request_sent": false, "location": "Brussels; Our website:", "profile_background_color": "F7F7F7", "contributors_enabled": false, "entities": {"url": {"urls": [{"display_url": "znconsulting.com", "expanded_url": "http://znconsulting.com", "url": "", "indices": [0, 23]}]}, "description": {"urls": []}}, "default_profile_image": false, "following": false, "followers_count": 2312, "description": "The #digital communication agency in #Brussels. Strategy, digital campaigns, analysis & #socialmedia. #Hyperthinking to give you the #DigitalAdvantage \\ud83d\\ude0e", "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "C7C7C7"}, "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, "contributors": null, "retweet_count": 0, "text": "Following user feedback, #Google is now blocking intrusive ads with a built-in adblocker in #Chrome \\u26d4\\n\\n", "retweeted": false, "truncated": false, "in_reply_to_user_id": null, "id_str": "967004613332303873", "source": "<a href=\\"https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\">TweetDeck</a>", "created_at": "Fri Feb 23 11:54:00 +0000 2018", "metadata": {"iso_language_code": "en", "result_type": "recent"}, "in_reply_to_screen_name": null, "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null, "entities": {"symbols": [], "urls": [{"display_url": "theguardian.com/technology/201\\u2026", "expanded_url": "https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2018/feb/15/google-adblocker-chrome-browser", "url": "", "indices": [103, 126]}], "user_mentions": [], "hashtags": [{"text": "Google", "indices": [25, 32]}, {"text": "Chrome", "indices": [92, 99]}]}, "coordinates": null, "in_reply_to_status_id": null, "place": null, "favorite_count": 0}')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object has no attribute 'toDF', Got this error!

Comment: Program Edited as per suggests and Updated in the question once again Please check and help me out!

Comment: If I make a SQL Context it How edits work on Streaming Context created? both contexts are different and work differently!

Comment: streaming context will lead to creation of dstreams but for dataframes in the function to exist, sql context is needed. Whatever you do inside the function 'convert' is not related to dstream or streaming context. That function is applied on each rdd in the dstream

Comment: SQL Context function cant is applied directly to Streaming Context functions. One has to create a streaming context which includes the functionality of SQL context.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46016586/how-to-save-spark-streaming-data-in-cassandra 

that issue of difference in contexts I faced in the above-questioned link.

Comment: 'This kafkaStream is having only properties of SSC but not SC, so here raised the issue of storing in to cassandra.' You are right. That is why here we are not trying to store the entire dstream but only dataframe inside it.

Comment: "raise ValueError("RDD is empty")
ValueError: RDD is empty"

Got this error!

Comment: because your batch interval is too short (1 sec). It did not get any data in streaming. try increasing it to 10 secs for once. check the edit.

Comment: raise ValueError("Some of the types cannot be determined by the "
ValueError: Some of the types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling)

Adding sample data fetched by CreateStream for more clear Understanding of data In question

Comment: yes. there might be some schema issues. From what i can guess, tweet json might be nested. You will need to flatten it so it can be converted.

Comment: Please help me out with that! If I flatten will I lose data? Added Data Structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165720/discussion-between-mayank-agrawal-and-ashrithgande).